# Sorting a column of CSV file resulting in 1123 appearing before 232

Tags: shell, sorting, csv, manpage

Specific question - bad title 
I am trying to sort a set of CSV data like -

```
2014/06/04 13:19:06.970,1124,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,782,1,0
2014/06/04 13:18:27.241,237,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,303,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:15.973,2224,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,1551,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:31.365,238,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:29.892,1429,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
```

using -

```
sort -t"," -k2,3
```

The result is

```
2014/06/04 13:19:06.970,1124,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,782,1,0
2014/06/04 13:18:27.241,1429,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,303,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:15.973,2224,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,1551,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:31.365,237,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:29.892,238,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
```

But I want something like -

```
2014/06/04 13:19:06.970,237,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,782,1,0
2014/06/04 13:18:27.241,238,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,303,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:15.973,1124,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,1551,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:31.365,1429,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:29.892,2224,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
```

or reverse of this (actually reverse is better for me).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-n` to have it sorted numerically:

```
$ sort -n -t"," -k2,3 file
2014/06/04 13:18:27.241,237,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,303,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:31.365,238,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:19:06.970,1124,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,782,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:29.892,1429,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:15.973,2224,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,1551,1,0
```

Or reverse with `-r`:

```
$ sort -rn -t"," -k2,3 file
2014/06/04 13:12:15.973,2224,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,1551,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:29.892,1429,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:19:06.970,1124,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,782,1,0
2014/06/04 13:12:31.365,238,Post Request,204,No Content,,true,,237,1,0
2014/06/04 13:18:27.241,237,Post Request,200,OK,text,true,,303,1,0
```

From `man sort`:

> **-n**, --numeric-sort
>
> compare according to string numerical value
>
> **-r**, --reverse
>
> reverse the result of comparisons

Comment: Learning like this is always fun. :)